# When importing float data from Excel using Pandas read_csv, numbers are rounded up to nearest integer

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter

I'm not sure how to read in csv data using Pandas read_csv without having the data rounded up. Here's the first few rows of the csv (opened in Excel, where the Excel column type is Number)

[image]

When I read this CSV into my Jupyter Notebook using Pandas, both columns are being rounded up.  I tried using the option float_precision = 'round_trip' and also first reading the columns in as str then converting to float, but once converted to float, the numbers are rounded up again.  I made sure that my Jupyter Notebook display precision is greater than two.

How do I read this data in while preserving the precision?

This is what the csv file looks like in Xcode

[image]

I first read in the csv with the following code

```
CPI = pd.read_csv('CPI.csv', dtype={'Year': str, 'Annual_Avg': np.float64 , 'Annual_Percent_Change': np.float64})
```

Afterwards, the dataframe looks like this:
[image]

After closing out my kernel and restarting Jupyter, I'm now seeing the decimals displayed again.  I don't know why it was initially rounding, it now looks ok.  Should I now delete this post? Not sure what the stackoverflow protocol is if you've 'solved' your own question.

Comment: Can you try to include `dtype : {‘column_name2’: np.float64,‘column_name2’: np.float64}` inside the `read_csv` method & try?

Comment: Could you show some rows of the `csv` file itself?

Comment: @moys When I add the dtype to read the columns as np.float64, the numbers are still rounded up. hpaulj, I posted a few rows from the CSV in the edit of my question.

Comment: So is it an Excel file or a CSV file? They're different. CSV files are plain text. Excel files (which end with xlsx) are not. You need to use read_csv or read_excel depending on what kind of file you want pandas to read.

Comment: @ba_ul, I should have been more clear.  I saved it as a CSV within Excel, so it's a CSV, and I'm using read_csv.

Comment: OK. Can you upload a part of the file or the whole file so that we can take a look and see what happens when we load the file using read_csv?

Comment: can you post the code you are trying to run?

Comment: @moys, here is the code to read in the file:

`CPI = pd.read_csv('CPI.csv', dtype={'Year': str, 'Annual_Avg': np.float64 , 'Annual_Percent_Change': np.float64})`